# Where the State of Stateful Operations saved in Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I was experimenting with 'flatMapGroupsWithState' with Spark Structured Streaming, the idea is interesting but now I am asking myself, due to distributed nature of the Spark, where is this State Information kept....

Let's say I have a Cluster 10, will all 10 share the storage load to keep this state information or there is risk that one node in the cluster can be overloaded?

I read somewhere that State object must Java Serialisable, considering Java Serialisation is extreme inefficient, is there a way to customise this to use Protobuffer or Avro, etc...

Thx for answers..

Answer (score 1):

> where is this State Information kept....

On executors.

By default there are 200 state stores as there are partitions. You can change it using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` configuration property. That gives you that the number of partitions is equivalent to the number of state stores. That also says that whatever you use as grouping keys will shuffle your data across partitions and (most likely) some of the available state stores are going to have no state at all (be empty).

> Let's say I have a Cluster 10, will all 10 share the storage load to keep this state information or there is risk that one node in the cluster can be overloaded?

Yes, but it's controlled by grouping keys and partitions, which is the code a Spark developer writes.

> I read somewhere that State object must Java Serialisable, considering Java Serialisation is extreme inefficient

No need to think about serialization as state stores are local to tasks (on executors).

> , is there a way to customise this to use Protobuffer or Avro, etc...

Sure. You should write your own state store implementation. By default there's one and only `HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider` that is configured using `spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass` internal configuration property.